# Variable name `PieGraphLayout` must match one of the following formats: camelCase eslint@typescript-eslint/naming-convention

Tags: typescript-eslint

This is a question similar to [Why eslint consider class as variable in naming-convention rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72629547/why-eslint-consider-class-as-variable-in-naming-convention-rule), but that one is pretty old and I see no consistency in the handling now.

When I statically import a class type then ESLint recognizes it as such and applies the class naming rule, for example:

```js
import { PieGraphLayout } from import("../console.worker-types");
```

When I do this with a dynamic import, however, I get an error:

```js
const { PieGraphLayout } = await import("../console.worker-types");
```

leads to:

> Variable name `PieGraphLayout` must match one of the following formats: camelCase eslint@typescript-eslint/naming-convention

I have to suppress this warning, but would like to modify my ESLint rules instead, if possible. My current naming-convention rule is:

```json
       "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
            "error",
            {
                "selector": "default",
                "format": [
                    "camelCase"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "regex": "^_",
                    "match": false
                }
            },
            {
                "selector": "class",
                "format": [
                    "PascalCase"
                ]
            },
            {
                "selector": "typeParameter",
                "format": [
                    "PascalCase"
                ]
            },
            {
                "selector": "enum",
                "format": [
                    "PascalCase"
                ]
            },
            {
                "selector": "enumMember",
                "format": [
                    "PascalCase"
                ]
            },
            {
                "selector": "typeAlias",
                "format": [
                    "PascalCase"
                ]
            },
            {
                "selector": "interface",
                "format": [
                    "PascalCase"
                ],
                "prefix": [
                    "I"
                ]
            }
        ],
```

What needs to be changed so that ESLint no longer gives a warning for such dynamic imports?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have defined formats for `variable` entities, and ESLint uses your `default` selector format, which is `camelCase` in the provided configuration.

To provide formats for a variable, please configure `variable` selector.

In your case, there should be something like

```js
{
  "selector": "variable",
  "format": [
    "PascalCase"
  ]
},
```

[Here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md#allowed-selectors-modifiers-and-types) is a doc for all available selectors.

Comment: But wouldn't it allow then pascal case for all variables? I don't want that. Variables should stay in camel case with leading low case letter.

Comment: Yep, it will allow it. I guess there is no difference between a dynamic import result and a typical return value from any function, so it is resolved as a variable. What is your goal to achieve here?